# The numpy function np.linspace is throwing a value error

Tags: python, numpy, conda

I've run the same code before on a different machine and it worked fine.

```
def interpolate2D(a, b, c, d, n=10):
    assert(len(a) == len(b) == len(c) == len(d))
    dim = len(a)

    # Define the interpolated values between the vectors a to b and the vectors c to d
    print(type(a), type(b), type(c), type(d))
    x = np.linspace(a, b, num=n)
    y = np.linspace(c, d, num=n)
    ...
```

Now, the first call to `np.linspace` throws the following error. Is this a versioning issue? I don't know what else it could be.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/Documents/all_is_all_poetry/in_two_dimensions/grid.py", line 268, in <module>
    'thing',
  File "/home/alex/Documents/all_is_all_poetry/in_two_dimensions/grid.py", line 242, in plot_along_space_2d
    vector_grid = interpolate2D(w, v, x, y, n=n)
  File "/home/alex/Documents/all_is_all_poetry/in_two_dimensions/grid.py", line 91, in interpolate2D
    x = np.linspace(a, b, num=n)
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/envs/nlp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py", line 124, in linspace
    if step == 0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

My numpy is up to date:

```
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.16.4'
```

Comment: what are you inputing for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`?

Comment: Can you provide the inputs?

Comment: your elements are some kind of iterable.  numpy.linspace used to only accept scalars and only now recently started accepting non-scalars.  you're anaconda verison of numpy is older.

Comment: Did you possibly check your `numpy` version out of your `nlp` virtual environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your anaconda environment is not on 1.16.4 and is on 1.15.x.

The line `if step == 0` was changed in version 1.16.0 to `if _nx.any(step == 0):` so that start and stop can be arrays.

Change log here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/58ebb6a7d77cf89afeb888a70aff23e03d213788#diff-12e00d917c1600a79611d57403cfbf70

You can see 1.15.4 here, and line 124 matches your error message above https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.15.x/numpy/core/function_base.py

Comment: This seems to be the error. I tried restarting a few times and only after the most recent restart, everything started working. I don't know why it didn't originally.

Comment: Glad I could help! :D